# Lagrange multipliers for finding area

Tags: area, lagrange-multiplier

Use the method of Lagrange multiplier to find the area of the intersecting
surface of $x^2- y^2 + 4z^2 = 1$ and $x + y + z = 0$. (Hint: the area of an ellipse equals to $\pi ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are the semi-axes of the ellipse.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: is it we have to find the points on the ellipse that is nearest to and farthest from the origin?

Comment: Are you sure that those two equations are correct? Per David G. Stork’s answer, the intersection of the plane and quadric is a hyperbola, not an ellipse. I suspect that there’s a sign error somewhere in your equations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what an ellipse has to do with this problem.

[image]